# Problem while deploying Azure static web app (Blazor)

Tags: blazor, azure-static-web-app

I wanted to publish my Blazor client side to Azure static web app with following locations:

```
app_location: "src/Client/Project.Client.Web"
api_location: ""
output_location: "wwwroot"
```

and I received an error:

> Failed to find a default file in the app artifacts folder (wwwroot).
> Valid default files: index.html,Index.html.
>
> If your application
> contains purely static content, please verify that the variable
> 'app_location' in your workflow file points to the root of your
> application.
>
> If your application requires build steps, please validate
> that a default file exists in the build output directory.

The app is buildable locally without problem, do you know where could be a problem ?
Or what do I do wrong ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/publish-app-service-static-web-app-api-dotnet/

Comment: I went through that like 3 times before, but this case wasnt mentioned there. Check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several hours of trial and error I stumbed upon a possibility to deploy a project from Visual Studio locally:

[image]

So I set up this local publishment and then I published it on my local drive. And thanks to that I found out that my `index.html` is not in the `wwwroot` as expected but in `wwwroot/app`.

So when I edited my deployment file: `azure-static-web-apps-asdasd-asdds-1234.yml` and changed: `output_location` from `wwwroot` to `wwwroot/app` it finally worked.

The `/app` subfolder was created probably (just speculation) because this app service has linked custom domain (subdomain): `app.project.fit`.

**EDIT:**
So the real cause of this `/app` subfolder was a specified property in `.csproj`

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <StaticWebAssetBasePath>app</StaticWebAssetBasePath> //<--- this
</PropertyGroup>
```

that was a leftover from DualHosted project of client and server. Example here: https://github.com/Kebechet/BlazorDualHostedExample